# Evitar recargar/refrescar Fragment de Android al cambiar la orientación de pantalla

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment

Estuve investigando un poco acerca de este tema, encontré una forma de evitar que mi Activity se recargue al rotar la pantalla agregando esta linea a mi Manifest **android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"**, pero si agregó dicha linea, esto evita que todos mis Fragments se recarguen.
El objetivo es lograr que solamente uno de mis Fragments conserve su estado, ya que voy agregando filas a una tabla dinámicamente, pero si cambio la orientación de la pantalla,estos datos se pierden.
Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias.

[image: Vista que quiero conserve su estado]

Answer (score 1):

Después de investigar por un rato, logré resolver mi problema, gracias a esta pagina:
[Handling Configuration Changes](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Configuration-Changes)

La forma de guardar el estado de la vista dentro de un Fragment, es simplemente creando los métodos **set** y **get** en este caso de un dato de tipo View, después dentro del método **OnCreateView** llamamos al método **setRetainInstance(true)** y finalmente
se hace la validación de si nuestra **View** es o no nula.

```
private View root;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                          ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

setRetainInstance(true);

if(getView() == null) {
    root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_venta, container, false);
}else {
    setView(root);
}

    return root;
}

public void setView(View root) {
     this.root = root;
}

public View getView() {
     return root;
}
```